# Execute function when script ends

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that starts by using `pushd` and I need to run `popd` in all exit paths.

Is it possible to register a function to be executed when the script ends? Something like `atexit` in C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
popd
yourscript
```

put it in a file like `popdir.bat` then instead of calling popd just call `popdir`

Comment: Shouldn't `popd` come after `yourscript`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @dbenham it depends on what the OP wants to do. If that's about the old folder then popd should come last